# Getting a map marker ID in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting my marker datas from my SQLite database. And I stored this datas in array list.

In my activity, I also create route between 2 markes. (One of those markers it's user's current location) And user click random marker, it's shows the route between this marker and user's current location.
But I have problem. Cause I don't know how do I know which marker has been clicked? Any idea?

Note: I'm using this work for routing
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

My database[image: screenshot]

**MapsActivity.java**

```
SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] getColumnName={"bakim_enlem,bakim_boylam,bakim_title"};
        Cursor imlec=db.query("bakim_yerleri", getColumnName, null, null, null, null, null);

        while(imlec.moveToNext())
        {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng
                    (imlec.getDouble(imlec.getColumnIndex("bakim_enlem")),imlec.getDouble(imlec.getColumnIndex("bakim_boylam"))))
                    .title(imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("bakim_title"))).
                    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapmarker)));

        }


        }



  //route code
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)
{
   //in default, you can write here and down there-> LatLng marker1
   if (marker.equals(**?**))
    {
        CoordinatorLayout rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapCoordinatorLayout);
        Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Rota oluşturuluyor...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(suanKonumumuz)
                .to(**?**)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use an `HashMap` for mapping your Marker with extra information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31272741/1584654

Comment: But this link is contains infowindows click event. I have problem with marker click. And their click functions is quite different.

Comment: Yes, but I was suggesting you to apply the same logic, using an `HashMap` when you add the Marker to the map, and then in your `onMarkerClick` get the data related with your Marker, using `map.get(marker)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding markers you can always use marker.setTag(ID) and when user click on the marker, try marker.getTag() to find out which marker was clicked.

Comment: I'll try that, will let you know the result. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Okay, in my code there is ".to()" function. And this function is accepting LatLng data type. I mean I need to get which marker has been clicked and get it's positon.

Comment: From where do you get these markers? What is your source of your data? Does your source contain anything that is unique? If yes, set that Id as a tag and then when the marker is clicked, check the tag and find out which marker it was. Hope this make sense

Comment: I'm using SQLite for this. I'm keeping them on database. But I have almost 25 marker.

Comment: When you store data in SQLite there must be a primary key? right? When you add markers on the map, set that id as the key. Then when you get a callback from marker, get the id from tag, query the database again with that id and retrieve your data.

Comment: bakim_id is primary key. I'll try and let you know asap. I'm gonna use SQL query like SELECT lng,lat FROM bakim_yerleri WHERE ID="markerTagID"